# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false after adding auth cookie

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code to add authentication cookie to the response and redirect to homepage

```
HttpCookie authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(username, true);
Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
Response.Redirect("~/Home/Home.aspx");
```

But in the Home.aspx, `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is still false. why?

Comment: can you share the code which is setting FormsAuthentication the cookie?

Comment: @Furqan, that's exactly what he showed: `Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);`.

Comment: @sean717, AFAIK FormAuthentication Cookies are set by calling `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName,[true/false]);`, not by adding it to response.

Comment: @Furqan, what do you think that the `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` method does? It calls the `FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie` first and then adds it to the response, exactly the same as what the OP did.

Comment: @Darin, AFAIK if the FormsAuthenticationCookie and response cookies are different in a way that if cokkies are disabled by the browser, the Forms authentication cookies value is automatically encrypted and appended to URL to maintain the user session, while setting cookies manually does not acheive this.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are correct. The SetAuthCookie method handles the scenario of the web browser having disabled cookies. But if this is not the case, the 2 calls should be equivalent. The thing is that the OP passed `true` as second argument. This means that he wants the browser to *remember* the user and the only way to achieve that is using cookies. So if he has disabled cookies in his browser he won't be able to implement his requirement anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the discussions. But my question remains. Why didn't it work?

Comment: @Sean717,  I know this is question is a little older, but for what it's worth using FormAuthentication.GetAuthCookie and then sending it to the client using Response.Cookies.Add worked fine for me.   Did you check to see if the cookie was sent to the client?   The only difference was I set false for creating a persistent cookie - but that shouldn't matter.  I know you answered below but there is no difference between using the more direct FormsAuthenticationTicket versus the methods in this answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it working. Here is it in nutshell

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
        username,
        DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
        isPersistent,
        userData,
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

      // Encrypt the ticket.
      string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

      // Create the cookie.
      Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));
```

I followed the code sample from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.aspx) MSDN page:

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to add the cookie to the response yourself.

You were doing this:

```
HttpCookie authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(username, true);
Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
Response.Redirect("~/Home/Home.aspx");
```

But instead of doing a `GetAuthCookie` and then adding it, you can just use `SetAuthCookie`:

```
HttpCookie authCookie = FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
Response.Redirect("~/Home/Home.aspx");
```

When you look at the [MSDN page for SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx), you see that it not only adds the cookie to the Response (or the URL), but it also creates and encrypts a ticket:

> Creates an authentication ticket for the supplied user name and adds it to the cookies collection of the response, or to the URL if you are using cookieless authentication.

That's probably why it doesn't work when you just try to add the cookie yourself.